# MitM attempt resulting in ICMP redirects

Tags: network, linux, man-in-the-middle

I am trying to 'man in the middle' a device on my wifi network. I have configured it to use my Linux machine (also in the wifi network) as a default gateway.

On the Linux (attack) host, I switched on IPv4 forwarding using

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then I start looking at the traffic from the victim device using wireshark. 
I then saw that the attack machine sends ICMP redirect packets to the victim device, pointing it to the actual default gateway in the network. That is, obviously, not what I want it to do.

Then I tried disabling ICMP redirects using

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0
```

That seemed to work, but after a while the redirect packets started to appear again...

Any clues to what I can do to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience this

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0
```

will not work properly on some systems what works for me is

```
echo 0 | tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/send_redirects
```

Comment: Yes this seems to work, instead of setting this for `all` interfaces I need to set it for the wifi interface specifically. Linux kernel bug?